# clip-path on YouTube iframe

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, clip-path

I am trying to make a polygon clip-path work on a YouTube iframe. It currently works on Chrome and Safari before the video is played (but not after), and not at all on Firefox. I have no idea why this is happening and have not found any examples of a clip-path working on a YouTube iframe.

```
<iframe width="320" height="256" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zkESoUBVQDs" style=" -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 100% 16%, 100% 89%, 0 64%); clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 100% 16%, 100% 89%, 0 64%);`" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mamd9us/3/)